How to capture the Radius and Direction of a Curve/Spline
I'm trying to make use of a Geometry Nodes Leaf/twig distribution from the Addon Mtree on my trees made with the Sapling Tree Gen addon (Sapling has much more control to build a tree and Mtree has a great leaf distribution nondestructive GN setup).
When Mtree generates the tree (trunk and branches) it creates two captured attributes named "radius" and "direction" that are called upon via the GN setup to control the distribution of the twigs...I'm trying to replicate those attributes.
I'm not sure if the attributes are generated off of the spline/curve or the actual geometry, maybe the UV's. I have the option to make use of the sapling tree curves if that's how it's done.
Is there a setup (possibly a GN setup) to capture those attributes and apply them to my tree geometry?.
I have this setup which kinda works, but is not correct...the results are random as the nodes would imply.

In this image are the results of the "radius attribute", note how the points on the left trunk and full tree are scaled based on the width/radius of the trunk and branches...this is the correct result. The trunk on the right is my setup (very random scale). The scale of the points is important as that's how the twigs are placed on the tree (from outer most "smallest points" to inner most "largest points"...I have a video showing this if needed)

Here is the GN setup (From Mtree) to distribute and control the twigs.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
My geometry is a tree made with the "Sapling Tree Generator" addon...I'm trying to add two attributes to control leaf distribution as is done in Mtree. Mtree does it with a script, I'd like to be able to create those attributes manually if possible.
Here's a grab of the script I believe Mtree uses to create those attributes...


This question needs a little more elaboration.
If you have access to Mtrees setup, please show it entirely. We also need to know what "your geometry" is, what is the input of the setups you show, how they're generated, etc.

I've added some additional information to the end of my question...not sure what else to provide.
